# StarTeam and Visual Studio 2010 Integration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, integration, starteam

I was searching for a plug-in that will integrate with StarTeam and allow user to check-in and check-out files directly through Visual Studio 2010 environment. I did found a StarTeam Visual Studio Client provides an integration that allows users of the Visual Studio IDE to manage their digital assets (files) and activities (requirements, tasks, defects) in their StarTeam repository from within the Visual Studio development environment.  Unfortunately this client works only with VS 2008 and not with Visual Studio 2010 and this is the vision of IDE that is I will be using for one of the project that I am workign on. I would really appreciate if someone could guide me in getting StarTeam integration with VS 2010.

Comment: What version of StarTeam are you using?

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of integration you can use:

**SCC Integration**: This is a standard that lets any development environment talk to any source control provider, if they both support the standard. (Visual Studio & StarTeam both do.)

**StarTeam Visual Studio Integration**: This is sort of a plug-in to Visual Studio that lets you access StarTeam and adds some additional features.

**SCC Integration** should let any version of StarTeam talk with any version of Visual Studio. However, with the **StarTeam Visual Studio Integration**, newer versions don't support older versions of StarTeam. 
For instance, the version of StarTeam Visual Studio Integration for Visual Studio 2010 only supports (I think) StarTeam 2009.

Even if you aren't able to use **StarTeam Visual Studio Integration**, **SCC Integration** should still work.

Comment: Do any of these work with Vs2010 in Windows 7? We have not been able to get it to work on W7 at all.

Comment: We use the SCC Integration with VS2010 and Windows 7.

Comment: I don't think we did anything super special. We're using StarTeam Server 2006 and StarTeam client 2008. What problems are you running into?